# unable to access jarfile via conda env

Tags: java, conda, nextflow

I downloaded a java software called "beagle" via conda (**java-jdk** and **java** were already installed). When I run the Nextflow (NF) pipeline (software is used in a process of NF), it says:

> unable to access jarfile beagle.24Aug19.3e8.jar

I activated the conda env, checked the location of the software, it is in

> <conda_env>/share/beagle-5.1_24Aug19.3e8-0/beagle.jar

and the example usage is like this:

```
java -jar beagle.24Aug19.3e8.jar
```

So, my command is correct.. I tried all the combinations in NF process like:

- java -jar /share/beagle-5.1_24Aug19.3e8-0/beagle.jar
- java -jar beagle.24Aug19.3e8.jar
- java -jar beagle.jar
- java -jar /share/beagle-5.1_24Aug19.3e8-0/beagle.24Aug19.3e8.jar

What am I missing? Why it is inaccessible? Thanks!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it but forgot to update here. In fact tool's manual says the usage of the software should be with:

```
java -jar beagle.jar
```

it worked only with "**beagle**" command. Did not delete the post since it may be helpful for smb else.

Cheers,

Comment: The Conda ENV provides a convenience [wrapper](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/tree/master/recipes/beagle) for the JAR. If you use it, then you don't need to specify a full path to the JAR or try to localize it in your process declaration. The "unable to access jarfile" is basically a file not found error. HTH.

Comment: Hey Steve! 

Thanks, yes, it helps too.